# How to find the n'th byte in a file

Tags: c++, byte

I have a somewhat unusual problem.  Because of my predecessor's design, I have a 27 MB file and I need to find a specific byte in it, like say the 100,000th byte.  I then have to delete everything between then 100,000th and 150,000th byte.

The file is broken up into a header file (which ends with `[END]` after about 10,000 characters) and the actual data, which is all in byte form.  The 27 million bytes are separated over about 15000 lines.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 2.7mb is not 27 million.

Comment: I'm not sure I see an actual question here, aside from the implied "plz send teh codez."

Comment: "Make it so" is not a question.

Comment: Can you use the fseek function to find the place.

Comment: The question is: Is there a way to find the n'th byte of a file no matter what line it is on? I could put each line into a string, then find the size of that string and add it to the number of bytes read, then move on to the next line until I hit my target byte, but that seems really slow and inefficient.

Comment: Yes, @user2761933, there are several ways to do that.  I doubt that really your question, though.

Comment: what is the problem of opening the file in binary mode (knowing the header size, and it seems reasonable that you know the size) and just do tell(sizeof(header) + n'th-byte-you-want-to-go-to) and from there do what you wish

Comment: Sean, fseek looks like it would be perfect, thank you.  And JohnDibling I don't want code to just be given to me, I just didn't know how to select a byte in the file and then delete a certain number of bytes. I am happy to do the actual coding myself.

Comment: It would be a good idea at this point to take your comments and update the question.

Comment: Fair enough.  You didn't ask "how can I seek to the nth byte in a file."  In fact you didn't ask anything.  You posted the program's requirements and asked for help, impying you wanted us to do all the work for you. In the future I'd recommend taking a little more time to craft your post so that your question is clear and unambiguous.  That way you may avoid getting downvoted and close-voted in to oblivion.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll remember that @JohnDibling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution in your case (unless you have strict restriction on space usage) would be to copy your file into another skipping bytes that you do not need. Depends on how you count nth byte you may need to open files in binary mode. You may rename source file to temp open new file with original name, do actual copy and delete source. Or you can copy content to temp file, then delete original and rename temp into original name. 
If you have restriction on disk space you can store file remaining (from 150,000th to the end in your example) truncate original file to 100,000th and then copy that remaining back.

Answer (score 0):

copy file 1 to file to skip the unwanted area with seekg.

```
//open the files:
ifstream fin("filename.ext",ios::in|ios::binary);
ofstream fout("filename.ext",ios::out|ios::binary);

size_t position = ?? ;// position in file
size_t size = ??; //size you want to read

char buffer[BUFFSIZE];
//go to position:
fin.seekg(position);

//read from position 
while(size > 0){
  fin.read(buffer, MIN(size, BUFFSIZE));
  size_t count;
  fout.write(buffer, count);
  size -= count; 
}
```